# why use a non-member function?

Tags: c++

I am learning about the `friend` keyword in C++ and I am wondering why have a non-member function and use the `friend` keyword when you can just make the non-member function a member function? I hope I made my question clear enough, thank you!

Comment: A common example I can think of is overloading the `ostream` operator.

Comment: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm

Comment: @JerryCoffin:  That's a great reference, but, to be fair, Sutter is mostly talking about _non-friend_ non-memebers, and the question is about _friend_ non-members.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: To an extent true -- but IMO, the primary question is about member vs. non-member. Whether to make it a friend just comes down to a question of whether it needs access to internals or the public interface is adequate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because sometimes you need to create an overloaded operator where your class type is on the right-hand-side. This must be implemented as a free function. Classic example:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, my_type const& my)
{
    // print out `my` into `str`---requires `friend` if using
    // private members of `my_type`
    return str;
}
```

Comment: To make it clear, member functions always have their own object type as first argument, but for cout << <object>, you want cout (ostream) as first argument. So this can't be implemented as a member function. Same applies to overloading op + such that 6 + obj works. Here 6 is the first param not belonging to class.